# Problem with chilkat ActiveX HTTP component with Redirect

Tags: chilkat

I used this script to check the last redirect url:

```
        set http = CreateObject("Chilkat_9_5_0.Http")

        http.FollowRedirects = 0

        ' resp is a Chilkat_9_5_0.HttpResponse
        Set resp = http.QuickGetObj(link)
        If (http.LastMethodSuccess = 0) Then
            wscript.echo http.LastErrorText
            WScript.Quit
        End If

        status = resp.StatusCode
        wscript.echo "HTTP Response Status: " & status
        wscript.echo "Redirect URL >>>: " & http.FinalRedirectUrl
        nextUrl = http.WasRedirected 

        loopCount = 0
        Do While (status = 302 OR status = 301)

            wscript.echo "HTTP Response Status: " & status
            wscript.echo "Redirect URL >>>: " & http.FinalRedirectUrl


            nextUrl = http.FinalRedirectUrl
            ' resp is a Chilkat_9_5_0.HttpResponse
            Set resp = http.QuickGetObj(nextUrl)
            If (http.LastMethodSuccess = 0) Then
                wscript.echo http.LastErrorText
                WScript.Quit
            End If

            status = resp.StatusCode
            wscript.echo "HTTP Response Status: " & status

            ' For safety, prevent infinite loops by
            ' keeping a loopCount and only allows following a max 
            ' of 10 redirects:
            loopCount = loopCount + 1
            If (loopCount > 10) Then

                wscript.echo "Too many redirects."
                WScript.Quit
            End If
        Loop
```

This code prints the 301 status code correctly, but it doesn't print the http.FinalRedirectURL (it's blank).

I also tried with the url https://www.businessonline.it/articoli/guida-al-nuovo-regime-forfettario-2016-e-2017.html

The output is:

```
Link: https://www.businessonline.it/articoli/guida-al-nuovo-regime-forfettario-2016-e-2017.html
HTTP Response Status: 301
Redirect URL >>>: 

HTTP Response Status: 301
Redirect URL >>>: 
ChilkatLog:
  QuickGetObj:
    DllDate: Oct 28 2019
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.80
    UnlockPrefix: BRKEVN.XXXXXXXXXXX
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: ActiveX
    VerboseLogging: 0
    Component successfully unlocked using purchased unlock code.
    url: 
    verb: GET
    quickRequestDb:
      url: 
      getHttpConnectionByUrl:
        urlObject_loadUrl:
          No domain in URL
          url: 
        --urlObject_loadUrl
      --getHttpConnectionByUrl
    --quickRequestDb
    Failed.
  --QuickGetObj
--ChilkatLog
```

I used both chilkat 9.5.0.70 and 9.5.0.80.
If I set FollowRedirects to 1, the first StatusCode is "200" and I can't get the url.

Can you help me?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Lorenzo,

The problem had to do with QuickGetObj and QuickGet.  The QuickGetStr method worked fine for the WasRedirected and FinalRedirectUrl properties.

Here's a new 32-bit ActiveX build with the fix:

32-bit: https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkatax-9.5.0-win32-1630.zip